# Python- Do not want letters or numbers outside of range input

Tags: python, exception, input

I want the program to only allow the numbers 1-4 to be used as input and not any letters or numbers outside of that range. This is the code I have right now but it is not working:

```
 # Get the user's choice.
 choice = int(input("what would you like to do ? "))

 # Validate the choice.
 while choice < 1 or choice > 4:
    try:
        choice = int(raw_input("Enter a valid choice: "))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Please enter a numeric value.")

 # return the user's choice.
 return choice
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Seems to behave correctly for me if I run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is your solution**

```
while True:
    try:
        choice = int(input("what would you like to do ? "))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid choice.Valid choises are between 1-4.")
        continue
    if choice<1 or 4<choice:
        print ("Invalid choice.Valid choises are between 1-4.")
        continue
    else:
        print ("some codes will work on here..")
```

Comment: will not work for input like " hello choice 3", it will take 3

Comment: hello choice 3? He wants integer, not strings. Why you input hello choice?

Comment: @Hackaholic _I want the program to only allow the numbers 1-4_ see that?

Comment: Im getting this error: NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: @FaRi if its your solution please check it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 def ask():
     # Get the user's choice.
     choice = raw_input("what would you like to do ? "))
     return choice

 #you can put this in while True infinite loop if you want it to ask again and again
 choice = ask()

 # Validate the choice.
 if choice.isdigit():
    if (choice > 0) and (choice < 5):
        print choice
    else:
        print "Input must be between 1 and 4!"
 else:
    print "Input must be digit!"
```

Using isdigit() you check if string is digit. It returns True or False. Here's some doc:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit

I hope this helps and fits ur needs ;)

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
def get_choice():
    while True:
        choice = raw_input("Enter a valid choice between 1 and 4: ")
        if choice.isdigit():
            if 1<= int(choice) <=4:
                print choice
                return choice
        else:
            print ("Please enter a numeric value.")
```

`str.isdigit()` : check for if the string is digit or not, if digit return True else False

Comment: You can also do `1 <= choice <= 4` to make the condition less verbose

Comment: @DSM open terminal and give it a try:>>> '1' > 2
True
>>> '1' < 2
False

Comment: Erm, didn't you notice that it said that `'1' > 2` was True?  Do you notice anything strange about that?

Comment: @DSM yes i notice that why i gave it to you